# Rounding within a range in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that Math.round rounds the number to nearest integer.

What I need is to round a number within specific range. For e.g.

If num=4.50  and range=0.1

so number in +- 0.1 of 4.5 should be rounded to 4.5

i.e. mathrangeRound(4.44) =4.5 and MathrangeRound(4.6) =4.5

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `Math.round(num/range)*range`

Comment: What about `4.8` or `4.2`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I tried with that
for 4.44 I am getting 4.4 for range 0.1. I already have the target number given. In that numbers +- delta proximity number should be rounded to that target number

Comment: @Rajesh, both 4.8 and 4.2 are not in the +- 0.1 range of 4.5

Comment: @Artiga My query is how do you decide the base value(4.5)? Is it supplied as well?

Comment: @Rajesh, yes, it is supplied already.

Comment: But what should 4,8 become after having been runned through the yet to be discovered rounding formular?

Comment: The question is not clear.  Maybe give more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
function aggr(num, pre, base){
  return Math.abs(base - num) <= pre ? base : num
}

console.log(aggr(4.44, 0.1, 4.5))
console.log(aggr(4.6, 0.1,4.5))
console.log(aggr(4.8, 0.1,4.5))
console.log(aggr(4.8, 0.3,4.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like  :

```
var num = 4.5;
var range = 0.1;
input = 4.44;
if (Math.abs(num-input) < range) input = num;
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Couldnt choose more than one answer as a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = Math.abs(x-num)<=range?num:x
```

where res is the rounded off value and x is the input number